# Как правильно согласовать: в восьми из десяти предыдущих игр (играх)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно согласовать предложение: "Спартак набирал очки в восьми из десяти предыдущих игр (играх)"? Какое существительное (игр или играх) должно стоять в конце, от какого слова оно зависит — «восьми» или «десяти»? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Словосочетание, в которое объединены числительное и существительное (кроме *один, одна, одно, одни*), обладает особым типом синтаксической связи.

1. В именительном и винительном падежах числительное управляет существительным:
   *На острове **стояли*** (что? И. п.) ***два*** дерева.
   *Я **видела*** (что? В. п.) ***два*** дерева.
2. В остальных падежах числительное **согласуется** с существительным:
   *Окно затенено* (чем? Т. п.) *двумя деревьями.*

"Спартак" набирал очки (в чём? П. п.) в восьми [играх] (из чего? Р. п.) из десяти предыдущих игр.

Правильно:
**"Спартак" набирал очки в восьми из десяти предыдущих игр.**

Answer (score 0):

Одно существительное опускается, а второе согласуется с тем словом, к которому относится:
...в восьми из десяти предыдущих **игр**.
...в восьми **играх** из десяти предыдущих.